# Adobe Analytics | Merge data from multiple report suites

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are capturing information for consumer sites in multiple different report suites.
Is it possible to merge all these data to a parent report suite without adding that parent report suite's account id in `s_account` variable?

For example

**Site 1 uses report-suite1**

```
s_account  = "report-suite1";
```

**Site 2 uses report-suite2**

```
s_account = "report-suite2"
```

Instead of using

```
s_account = "report-suite1,report-suite2"
```

is it possible to merge the data to a 3rd virtual account from the Reports console itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can route data to a separate *fully fledged* report suite is either via javascript (e.g. setting `s_account` as you have shown in your post), or to ask Adobe To create a VISTA rule.

You didn't state your reasons for not wanting to throw a "global" rsid into your js code. Is it because you don't have the technical resources/ability to do it? If so, and if you want a full 3rd rsid for all the data to go to, then you can ask Adobe to create a VISTA rule. It should be fairly easy for them to setup, but they will charge you for it. And I think they will create one for each report suite. I don't generally recommend going this route unless you really have to, though. Mostly because the cost, but also because you don't have personal visibility into it.

Alternatively, if you do have the tech resources to update the js code, but the cost of throwing another rsid into the mix is an issue (from extra server hits), then you may want to consider replacing all of your report suites with a single global report suite, e.g.

`s_account='report-global';`

Then, create a [Virtual Report Suite](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/reference/vrs-considerations.html) for each site. You can go to `Components` > `Virtual Report Suites` to set them up. The TL;DR is you create them by pointing at your `report-global` rsid as the source and then creating a segment based off something unique to the site (e.g. the domain, or maybe some `eVar` with a site-specific value).

The major downside to going the virtual report suite route is historical data from your previous report suites will not be available in the same place as this new global report suite and its virtual report suites. But it's a "one time migration" thing, and the historical data won't be lost; you'll just have some extra work on your end referencing it in the old rsids, esp if you want to compare historical to current in the new (virtual) risds.

The 2nd major thing to consider is unique limits. Not sure how much traffic / unique values vars get on your sites, but there is a monthly unique value limit you may have to consider with all of the sites going to the same report suite.  Beyond looking at tricks to make values less unique on a case by case basis (e.g. removing query param string from URLs), there isn't a good way to solve for this except to stick with separate rsids.  Well.. Adobe will increase unique limit on certain vars if you ask them, but it will cost you..

Another alternative to consider is a [**Rollup** report suite](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/reference/rollup_report_suite.html). If you go to `Admin` > `Report Suites`, where your current report suites are listed.  To the left you should see **Rollups** and an **Add** link next to it. This will create a **Rollup** report suite made up of data from one or more report suites.

Note though that a **Rollup** report suite is not the same as full fledged report suite. Please refer to the link above for full details/limitations, but the main benefit is it won't cost you anything except the couple of minutes to set it up in the interface. But the limitations of it.. the main points of note are you only get aggregated data, data is not deduped between the rsids, and many reports are limited or not available. In practice, I rarely ever see anybody actually go this route because it's too limited. But hey, maybe it's good enough for you.